# Array associates string to image

Tags: php

With this code I should associate the flag with the relevant country.

```
//  ID            String
//   1            Italy, USA, Germany
//   2            Italy, USA
//   3            Italy
//   4            Italy, United Kingdom

$sql = "SELECT country  FROM film where film_id = 4";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
while ($row = $result->fetch_array()) {

    $str = $row['country'];
    $group1 = array("Italy"=>"it.png","Russia"=>"ru.png","USA"=>"us.png",
    "France"=>"fr.png","United Kingdom"=>"uk.png","Sweden"=>"se.png",
    "Denmark"=>"dk.png","Germany"=>"de.png","Poland"=>"pl.png",
    "Japan"=>"jp.png");


    $count_words = str_word_count($str);
    switch ($count_words){
        case 1:
            list($uno) = explode(',', $str);
            foreach ($group1 as $string){
                if (strpos($uno, $string)!==false){
                }
                $primo = $uno . ' <img src="img/separate/'.$string.'">';
             }
                echo $primo;
            break;
        case 2:
            list($uno, $due) = explode(',', $str);
            foreach ($group1 as $string) {
                if (strpos($uno, $string)!==false){
                }
                if (strpos($due, $string)!==false){
                }
                $primo = $uno . ' <img src="img/separate/'.$string.'">';
                $secondo = $due . ' <img src="img/separate/'.$string.'">';
            }
                echo $primo . ', ' . $secondo;
            break;
        case 3:
             list($uno, $due, $tre) = explode(',', $str);
             foreach ($group1 as $string) {
                if (strpos($uno, $string)!==false){
                }
                if (strpos($due, $string)!==false){
                }
                if (strpos($tre, $string)!==false){
                }
            $primo = $uno . ' <img src="img/separate/'.$string.'">';
            $secondo = $due . ' <img src="img/separate/'.$string.'">';
            $terzo = $tre . ' <img src="img/separate/'.$string.'">';
            }
            echo $primo.', '.$secondo.', '.$terzo;
            break;
        default:
            echo 'no match';
    }
```

The data is taken from the 'Country' column and, to test it, it is in this format:
- Italy
- Italy, USA
- Italy, USA, Germany
- Italy, United Kingdom

There are two problems:
The strings are displayed correctly, but the flag is always the Japanese one (jp.png)
During the tests I noticed that if I put the corresponding ID to: Italy, United Kingdom
the two strings are displayed plus a third flag (without the string) and error:
Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in C: xampp htdocs online js_php.php 148
line 148: list ($ one, $ two, $ tre) = explode (',', $ str);

I don't think the cause is this line but the white space between 'United' and 'Kingdom'
since Italy, USA (2 strings) is displayed without error

Please, I need help associating the right flag and
solve the problem that causes error

Comment: Isn't there supposed to be an ELSE here:`if (strpos($uno, $string)!==false){
                }
                if (strpos($due, $string)!==false){
                }
                $primo = $uno . ' <img src="img/separate/'.$string.'">';
                $secondo = $due . ' <img src="img/separate/'.$string.'">';`

Comment: The bigger problem seems to be that you're storing arrays in your database as comma-separated strings. Make use of a bridging table, and have countries as one table and films as another. Then you can just reference all of the country IDs for each film (in the bridging table), and you don't have to worry about `explode()` and `strpos()`.

Comment: thanks for the answers
- djunehor: even if I put ELSEIF nothing changes.
@Obsidia Age: I did as you said and in fact it's simpler, but
with code above I avoid adding a table
I think the first problem is the array and the second the 'delimeter'
in 'explode', but I can't solve

Comment: update: changing 'United Kindom' to United-Kingdom error disappeared

Comment: SOLVED.....case 1:
            list($uno) = explode(', ', $str);
            if (isset($group1[$uno])){
                $primo = $uno. ' <img src="img/separate/'.$group1[$uno].'">';
            }